# Build Python package with C bindings in Windows (VC90) causes LNK1181 fatal error

Tags: python, c, linker, distutils, libspotify

I'm trying to build a Python package (pyspotify) with bindings to a C library (libspotify).

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and have installed VS2008 Express for some required commandline tools.

When I call `python setup.py build` from the Command Prompt (with Admin rights) I get the following output:

```
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'spotify._spotify' extension
```

And then ~18 of these, one for each .c file in the package:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Isrc -Ic:\Python\Python27\include -Ic:\Python\Python27\PC
/Tcsrc\module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.obj
module.c
```

And then the showstopper:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /DLL /nologo
/INCREMENTAL:NO /LIBPATH:c:\Python\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Python\Python27\PCb
uild spotify.lib /EXPORT:init_spotify build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.ob
j build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\session.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\
link.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\track.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
\src\album.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\albumbrowser.obj build\temp.win3
2-2.7\Release\src\artist.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\artistbrowser.obj
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\search.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pla
ylist.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\playlistcontainer.obj build\temp.win3
2-2.7\Release\src\playlistfolder.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\image.obj
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\user.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyspo
tify.obj build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\toplistbrowser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win3
2-2.7\spotify\_spotify.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\_spotify.lib
 /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\_spotify.pyd.manifest
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'spotify.lib'
error: command '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.
exe"' failed with exit status 1181
```

And I have tried to search for this LNK1181 error, but all answers seems to be about remembering quotes around string, or some settings in VS which I in this case has no control over.

Comment: "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'spotify.lib'"

Comment: Is `spotify.lib` on your `LIB` path?

Comment: I don't know where spotify.lib is supposed to be, so no, I don't think so. Is it a VS generated file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the appropriate version of libspotify from [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/#download) unzip it and put it in the same directory that you are trying to build in, (easiest place), or tell VS where to find it.

Comment: This looks like a solution. I already had the libspotify.lib file there, but had to rename it to spotify.lib before it worked. Thanks :)